Hide certain user roles from contributors
I have Contributors on my site who have access to add/remove roles from other users. However, I have a handful of roles that allow varying degrees of backend access that I don't want those Contributors to have the ability to assign to other users. Is there a way to hide certain user roles from being visible for Contributors to choose?

Have you customized the Contributor role? I wouldn't expect that the default WordPress role would allow for privileges escalation such as this.

I have, but it only allows me to give the "edit users" capability. I need Contributors to have that capability, but not have access to all of the role options they can assign with that capability.

This will mostly likely need to be done in code, I don't think a plugin will allow you to do this. I honestly don't know all what you'll need to do, either. First you'll have to filter the options presented to the user to only allow your subset of roles so that the other options aren't offered. Make sure you don't "remove" ones you don't want, but instead only "allow" ones you do. Then you'll need to guard the actual database update to re-check that your rules are enforced.
